# I am not able to `use` or `namespace` in laravel helper file

Tags: php, laravel, helper

I have created helper file in laravel. I want to use laravel functionalities.

I am not able to use `use` or namespace template in helper file.

code of helper file.

```
namespace App\Helpers;

class CommonFunctions {

    public static function get_cat() {  

    }
}
```

I have linked this helper in `config/app.php`

[image]

When I use `namespace` in helper file then this error is displaying

[image]

Blade file code

[image]

Comment: Try to execute in console "composer dumpautoload"

Comment: I already done this, without namespace helper working fine.

Comment: Actually, Problem is I am not able to execute database queries in helper, I tried `use DB` but showing above error when I add `use` or `namespace` statements in helpers

Comment: Why is the class being called in a blade?

Comment: CommonsFunctions is helper file. it has some commons functions use in complete website... Please let me if is there any better way to do this

Comment: I am doing customization in laravel website, this file is developed by previous developer to achieve client need

Comment: @ShishilPatel Show that blade code.

Comment: code added... its just load of categories, means there other functions also which will be going to use in this.

Comment: but actual problem in I am not able to use database queries in helper file

Comment: `use App\Listing;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use File;
use DateTime;
use DB;`

Comment: @ShishilPatel ok, what is your exact question? The issue that you posted or not able to do DB queries in helper file? Also, please tag usernames by having `@` before(since there are more than 2 people in the conversation), else I won't be notified.

Comment: @vivek_23 sorry for not mentioning name in comments, Yes, I want to use DB queries and other model in helper file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the issue.

Actually I am migrating site from laravel 5.2 to 5.7 and I was copying the old helper file to new that's why I got this error..

Previously I was using `use` and `namespace` together but after adding `use` statements only I solved the issue.

It might be the issue of namespace is not allowing in helper file, but in every solution and method of creating helper files there is namespace, so, I had never try to remove that line.

But now I got the solution...

Thanks for all who helped me.
Shishil Patel

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have syntaxis error in your helper.
anyways try to execute `php artisan config:clear` and then fix all errors.

I have done everything the same way and I haven't found any problem.

Comment: can you please elaborate ? where and what is error ?

Comment: for example you will get that error if you forget `<?php` open tag. Or if it should be `<?php` instead of  `<?`. What have you got after execute `php artisan config:clear` ?